# Calling a WS with Postman is done, but not from Java code

Tags: java, post, https, postman

I did a Post request by using Postman and I got a response, but when did the same resquest using OkHttpClient (same problem with HttpsURLConnection) in java I got a connection refused exception.

Below is my code (with fake data) :

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
String req = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\r\n" + 
 "<ApplicantTestRequest\r\n" + 
 "PositionID=\"48939014-b24f-4d74-8a44-9913cd9f8936\"\r\n" + 
 "ThirdPartyCandidateID=\"4152ab4r\"\r\n" + 
 "FirstName=\"Danny\"\r\n" + 
 "LastName=\"Givaty\"\r\n" + 
 "UserName=\"dannyg\"\r\n" + 
 "Password=\"2sEr#d!w@\"\r\n" + 
 "email=\"dannyg@careerharmony.com\"\r\n" + 
 "Telephone=\"5558586858\"\r\n" + 
 "Source=\"LinkeIn\"\r\n" + 
 "SkipToFirstRecruiterComponent = \"1\"\r\n" + 
 "Gender = \"1\"\r\n" + 
 "/>";

RequestBody reqbody = RequestBody.create(null, req);  

Request request = new Request.Builder()
 .url("https://staging.direct-assessment.net/RomaTestUI/forms/xmlregistrationandtestentry.aspx?XMLReadType=1")
 .method("POST",reqbody)
 .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
 .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
 .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
int responseCode = response.code();
System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
```

The result I got is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to staging.direct-assessment.net/185.52.110.193:443
...........
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

I can see below reason for this, I am also including a possible solution -

The issue could be related to HTTP_TRANSPORT_VERSION, can you check what version is sent via Postman and what is sent from the Java program. If the versions are different then set the HTTP_TRANSPORT_VERSION (similar to that of Postman request) in your java call.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I used all params sent by Postman in request but I still have the problem